# RecyclerView inside ConstraintLayout - Start position at top of parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, recyclerview-layout

To make things simple, I have a `ConstraintLayout` with 2 childs: a `RecyclerView` and a `Button`.

I want the `RecyclerView` to start showing from the top of the parent. 
If there are only a few items to show in `RecyclerView`, it should wrap them. Something like this:

[image]

But, if the `RecyclerView` has enough items to go till the end of the screen, it should go instead till the top of the `Button`, not till the bottom of its parent.
Like this:
[image]

To achieve this effect I tried the following combination:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This solution was perfectly fine when the `RecyclerView` has only a few items to show. Otherwise, if it has to expand beyond the screen, it will go behind the `Button`.

After modifying the above xml to (note the line `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/my_button"` at `RecyclerView`):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/my_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result I get is:

[image]

That is, the `RecyclerView` is positioning at the center between parent's top and button's top. 
This would be OK if the `RecyclerView` has many items, but not if there are only a small number of items.

**Question**:
Is it possible to make my `RecyclerView` acting like:

1. Regardless to the number of items, make its top positioning to be at the top of its parent.
2. If there are few items, just wrap the content till the bottom of the last item.
3. If there are many items, expand till the top of the `Button`, not till the bottom of the `parent`

?

P.S. The solution should be considered using as parent `ConstraintLayout` only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` attribute with a value of `0` to align your `RecyclerView` to its top constraint (`1` would align to the bottom constraint). Both top and bottom constraints need to be set to use this bias. On the other hand, if the bottom constraint wasn't set then you wouldn't be able to prevent the `RecyclerView` from overlapping with the button. That's why it's important to set the bottom constraint and  keep the `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` to make sure that the `View's` constraint are enforced when its height is set to `wrap_content`.

The top constraint of your `RecyclerView` is also incorrect as its top should be constained to the top of the parent and not the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/my_button"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: "The top constraint of your `RecyclerView` is also incorrect as its top should be constained to the top of the parent and not the bottom." Sorry for that. It was a typing mistake of mine. Having this in mind, does it change anything in your solution?

Comment: No, other than that I only added the `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"` attribute to what you already had.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/my_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```